# Return JSONP from OnError Pipeline using NancyFX

Tags: asp.net, api, jsonp, nancy, onerror

I've got a simple API that is returning JSON.
There is a use case for certain clients to require a JSONP response.

Nancy returns JSONP naturally if you provide a callback parameter (super happy awesome!).

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to handle exceptions, I'm just getting JSON back when I return a Nancy response.
Seems like the JSONP functionality is only baked into the AfterRequest pipeline?

My error handling:

```
public class ErrorHandlingStartup : IApplicationStartup
{
    public void Initialize(IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        pipelines.OnError.AddItemToEndOfPipeline((ctx, exception) =>
        {
            var response = ErrorResponse.FromException(exception);

            return response;
        });
    }
}
```

The nancy JsonP class:
https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/Jsonp.cs

Is there anything simple that I'm missing or do I need implement the JsonP functionality to also cover OnError?